# WordPress: Can you add an Excerpt on a PDF

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

Is it possible to add an Excerpt on a PDF document. Whenever I use the search function on my website I can see the PDFs results, but the text below the link says "No excerpt available". I tried adding text into the Description and Caption fields, but it did not work.

[image]

I tried going through the media library > clicking the file > Edit more details then when the file document opens I clicked on the Share Options at the top of the page, but there is no Excerpt option available.

I can see the Excerpt option in Pages and Posts, but not on PDFs.

Is there a way to add Excerpts to PDF documents?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any plugins nor native way to do it but I had a similar problem on one of my last projects and here are my solutions.

Either... Creating a child post dedicated to that pdf and copying the content, outputting the child post content onto the parent post.

Or... Simply adding a description to the uploaded media (here the pdf) and outputting the description onto the post.

I went for the second one for dev time restriction, but the first one was also pretty cool because we could add long format additional information linked to the pdf.

Hope that will help!